# Unable to get product image in tpl file prestashop

Tags: php, html, prestashop-1.7

I have written a code in php which gets the product image link in prestashop. The Link I get is correct and it works but when I and add it in the image tag I get http 404 not found.

I know what the problem is but I am unable to solve. I have posted the error I am getting. I didn't post any code since I don't think the error is code related (and the code is working fine too).

**The link I have of the product image:**

http://localhost/prestashop/12-home_default/printed-summer-dress.jpg

This works if I just copy and paste it in my browser, But when I send it to tpl file the link doesn't get changed and it works the same as above but when I add it in the image tag i.e. `<img src="product link">`

**I get a new link:**

`http://localhost/prestashop/en/module/quotation/localhost/prestashop/12-home_default/printed-summer-dress.jpg`

> This throws a http 404 not found error

As you can see both the links are different. I can post the code if you like. If anyone wants to know how I am getting the links, I'll post it gladly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error it is clear that your are trying to load the file `localhost/prestashop/12-home_default/printed-summer-dress.jpg`
from the page `http://localhost/prestashop/en/module/quotation/`

The problem with your code is, the link is getting generated as a relative link rather than an absolute link.

To fix this, add the protocol `http://` as prefix to your image path to convert it to an absolute link in your tpl.

Comment: yes you are correct, I am loading the file from the page. adding http:// solved it. thanks